# SparkPost - not receiving Click Events

Tags: java, sparkpost

So, I have an http endpoint for receiving different types of events from SparkPost (such as Delivery, Bounce, Complaint, Open Track, ...). Everything works just fine, but I don't get any posts about Click events. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
 private void sendEmail(String from, String[] recipients) throws SparkPostException {
    TransmissionWithRecipientArray transmission = new TransmissionWithRecipientArray();

    ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    tags.add("tag #1");
    tags.add("tag #2");
    // Populate Recipients
    List<RecipientAttributes> recipientArray = new ArrayList<RecipientAttributes>();
    for (String recipient : recipients) {
        RecipientAttributes recipientAttribs = new RecipientAttributes();
        recipientAttribs.setAddress(new AddressAttributes(recipient));
        recipientAttribs.setTags(tags);
        recipientArray.add(recipientAttribs);
    }
    transmission.setRecipientArray(recipientArray);

    // Populate Substitution Data
    Map<String, Object> substitutionData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    substitutionData.put("link", "http://www.google.com?utm_campaign=test_campaign");


    OptionsAttributes optionsAttributes = new OptionsAttributes();
    optionsAttributes.setClickTracking(true); // THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO MAKE A DIFFERENCE
    optionsAttributes.setOpenTracking(true);


    transmission.setSubstitutionData(substitutionData);
    transmission.setOptions(optionsAttributes);
    transmission.setCampaignId("test_campaign");

    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
    metadata.put("user_type", "test");
    transmission.setMetadata(metadata);
    transmission.setReturnPath("example@some-mail.com");
    // Populate Email Body
    TemplateContentAttributes contentAttributes = new TemplateContentAttributes();
    contentAttributes.setFrom(new AddressAttributes(from));
    contentAttributes.setSubject("Your subject content here.");
    contentAttributes.setText("Your Text content here.");

    contentAttributes.setHtml("<p>Your <b>HTML</b> content here. {{ link }}</p>");

    transmission.setContentAttributes(contentAttributes);

    transmission.setContentAttributes(contentAttributes);

    // Send the Email
    RestConnection connection = new RestConnection(this.client, getEndPoint());
    Response response = ResourceTransmissions.create(connection, 0, transmission);

    System.out.println("Transmission Response: " + response);
}
```

Comment: Hey @peech :) Have you sent one of those emails to yourself? I'm thinking your link is getting escaped since you are using double curly braces. Try triple curlies {{{ link }}} to prevent html escaping.

Comment: This also doesn't work :/ If I put `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` directly in `contentAttributes.setHtml()`, I receive a Click Event. When putting it in from `substitutionData`, Click Event does not arrive.

Comment: In the email you receive, does the domain point to the SparkPost click tracking server, i.e. spgo.io, or is it google.com still?

Comment: it's still google.com

Comment: This is effectively an order of operations thing. When you're personalizing an entire link, our template engine needs to be able to see the url scheme to make sure it doesn't try to link wrap a `mailto:` link, for example. I'll put more detail in an answer.

Comment: Another note, bare links in html parts won't be wrapped for tracking unless they're inside `<a href="...">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the SparkPost template engine to only personalize `http(s)?` urls, and not wrap things like `mailto:a@b.com`, the scheme (`http://` or `https://`) needs to be in the template, as opposed to in the substitution data. Here's an example:

Template:

`This is a link to <a href="http://{{{myurl}}}">somewhere awesome</a>!`

Substitution Data:

`substitutionData.put("myurl", "www.google.com?utm_campaign=test_campaign");`

There are actually three changes here - the second one is using triple curlies `{{{` instead of `{{` double curlies, to avoid html-escaping the contents of the substitution variable. And the third is to put the url inside an anchor tag, since SparkPost won't wrap bare links.

Comment: Thank you, this worked as it was intended. Can't believe I didn't think of that myself ...